# Unable to import .so file in python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Note that this is all being run in Google Colab.

The `.so` extension module was written in C++/Cuda and built using Ninja.

The issue I'm having is understanding why I am unable to import this `.so` extension module.

As I said, I am using Google Colab. What is incredibly confusing is that when I `cd` into the directory containing the `.so` extension module `_ext`, I am able to import it perfectly fine, and all intended functionality works. However, when I try to import it from a `.py` file through a series of imports,

I.e.

> File `x` imports `y` which imports `z` which imports said `.so` extension module.

it says that the module cannot be found. I've tried adding the file to sys.path, but nothing works.

Below is the file folder structure, and the colab code/error output.

#### File Folder Structure

```
├── CenterNet
│   ├── data
│   ├── exp
│   ├── experiments
│   ├── images
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── models
│   ├── NOTICE
│   ├── readme
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── src
│       ├── demo.py
│       ├── _init_paths.py
│       ├── lib
│       │   ├── datasets
│       │   ├── detectors
│       │   ├── external
│       │   ├── logger.py
│       │   ├── models
│       │   │   ├── data_parallel.py
│       │   │   ├── decode.py
│       │   │   ├── losses.py
│       │   │   ├── model.py
│       │   │   ├── networks
│       │   │   │   ├── DCNv2
│       │   │   │   │   ├── build
│       │   │   │   │   │   ├── lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
│       │   │   │   │   │   │   └── _ext.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
│       │   │   │   │   │   └── temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
│       │   │   │   │   ├── DCNv2.egg-info
│       │   │   │   │   ├── dcn_v2_onnx.py
│       │   │   │   │   ├── dcn_v2.py
│       │   │   │   │   ├── _ext.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so # <-- The file I want to import.
│       │   │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   │   │   │   ├── LICENSE
│       │   │   │   │   ├── make.sh
│       │   │   │   │   ├── README.md
│       │   │   │   │   ├── setup.py
│       │   │   │   │   ├── src
│       │   │   │   │   │   ├── cpu
│       │   │   │   │   │   ├── cuda
│       │   │   │   │   │   ├── dcn_v2.h
│       │   │   │   │   │   └── vision.cpp
│       │   │   │   │   ├── testcpu.py
│       │   │   │   │   └── testcuda.py
│       │   │   │   ├── dlav0.py
│       │   │   │   ├── large_hourglass.py
│       │   │   │   ├── msra_resnet.py
│       │   │   │   ├── pose_dla_dcn.py
│       │   │   │   ├── __pycache__
│       │   │   │   └── resnet_dcn.py
│       │   │   ├── __pycache__
│       │   │   │   ├── decode.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │   │   ├── model.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │   │   └── utils.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │   ├── scatter_gather.py
│       │   │   └── utils.py
│       │   ├── opts.py
│       │   ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── trains
│       │   └── utils
│       ├── main.py
│       ├── test.py
│       └── tools
```

#### Colab Code

```py
    %cd $root_dir
    %cd CenterNet/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2
    
    !ls
    
    import _ext 
    import sys
    
    print('I exist at - ', _ext.__file__, ' !')
    sys.path.insert(0, _ext.__file__)
    
    %cd $root_dir/CenterNet/src
    
    !python demo.py ctdet --demo /content/CenterNet/images/19064748793_bb942deea1_k.jpg --load_model ../models/ddd_3dop.pth
```

Output

```
/content
/content/CenterNet/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2

build       _ext.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  __pycache__  testcpu.py
DCNv2.egg-info  __init__.py               README.md    testcuda.py
dcn_v2_onnx.py  LICENSE                   setup.py
dcn_v2.py   make.sh                   src

I exist at -  /content/CenterNet/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/_ext.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so !
/content/CenterNet/src

['/content/CenterNet/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/_ext.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', '/content/CenterNet/src/lib', '/content/CenterNet/src', '/env/python', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycocotools-2.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 16, in <module>
    from detectors.detector_factory import detector_factory
  File "/content/CenterNet/src/lib/detectors/detector_factory.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .exdet import ExdetDetector
  File "/content/CenterNet/src/lib/detectors/exdet.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .base_detector import BaseDetector
  File "/content/CenterNet/src/lib/detectors/base_detector.py", line 11, in <module>
    from models.model import create_model, load_model
  File "/content/CenterNet/src/lib/models/model.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .networks.pose_dla_dcn import get_pose_net as get_dla_dcn
  File "/content/CenterNet/src/lib/models/networks/pose_dla_dcn.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .DCNv2.dcn_v2 import DCN
  File "/content/CenterNet/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/dcn_v2.py", line 17, in <module>
    import _ext as _backend
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ext'
```

I have no idea why I am able to import the `_ext` module when I `cd` into the directory it is contained but unable to import it otherwise; even when added to sys.path! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *DCNv2* is not in `sys.path`. Either call `sys.path.append(...)` or set env variable *PYTHONPATH=<path to DCNv2>*

Comment: @PatrikPolakovic Thank you! I am a little confused as to why this is necessary though - as it seems that I can import DCNv2 perfectly fine without adding it to the path, but I am unable to import the shared object extension module within, do you know what the reason for this might be?

Comment: *DCNv2* itself is a python package. So you can import from it and python knows what to do only when it is in the *path*. In the path means either you add it explicitly or set your working directory to *networks* dir. But in your script, your working dir is *CenterNet/src*, so python cannot find the *DCNv2* because *src* is not a python package and your only option is to add it to the path explicitly